# bootstrap tab not working separately

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website which do not base on any well known framework. Yet i decided to use bootstrap tabs as they are quite flexible and easy to use. So I've prepared such jsfiddle:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/tqmou6bp/3/)

unfortunatelly, its not working. Why is that? I took tab.js file from cdn. The code is pretty simple:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs:before,
.nav-tabs:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.nav-tabs:after {
  clear: both;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item + .nav-item {
  margin-left: .2rem;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem .25rem 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus,
.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
  border-color: #eceeef #eceeef #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.disabled,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.disabled:focus,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.disabled:hover {
  color: #818a91;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active:focus,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active:hover,
.nav-tabs .nav-item.open .nav-link,
.nav-tabs .nav-item.open .nav-link:focus,
.nav-tabs .nav-item.open .nav-link:hover {
  color: #55595c;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd transparent;
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs li a').tab();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the tab.js for Bootstrap 4.0 alpha, which seems to work a little bit different from the Stable Bootstrap 3 version.

Just include all of the Bootstrap 3 javascript from the [official CDN](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js), or include tab.js from another source.

Answer (score 2):

I guess adding just following code will work super, also you will not be needing `tab.js` **for this**.

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/tqmou6bp/10/)</kbd>**

**JQuery**

```
$("#tabs li").click(function(){
    $("#tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");      
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
    href = href.substring(1);
    $(".tab-content .tab-pane").removeClass("in active");
    $("#" + href).addClass("in active");
});
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include Bootstrap's CSS to get the tab styling: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Adding the CSS styles everything properly but the tabs panes still don't show when the corresponding tab is clicked.

Comment: Oops. Thought that was the poster's question based on the fiddle they put up.